# Why does my pre-signed URL for my s3 bucket look different when deployed?

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

My python (Django) application stores confidential documents and has a private bucket in AWS S3.

When you make a request for the resource, it uses boto3 to generate a pre-signed URL to be able to download the document.

The code to do so is as follows:

```
@staticmethod
def create_presigned_url(key_name, bucket_name=settings.AWS_PDF_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME, expiration=60):
    """
    Generate a pre-signed URL to share a PDF.
    :param key_name: string.
    :param bucket_name: string.
    :param expiration: Time in seconds for the pre-signed url to remain valid.
    :return: Pre-signed URL as a string. If error, returns None.
    """
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    try:
        response = s3_client.generate_presigned_url(
            'get_object',
            Params={'Bucket': bucket_name, 'Key': f"pdf/{key_name}"},
            ExpiresIn=expiration
        )
    except ClientError:
        return None

    return response
```

When I run my application locally, it works great. It generates a link I can use to download the document and it expires after 60 seconds. Such URL looks like this:

```
https://BUCKETNAME.s3.amazonaws.com/pdf/testuser1/dummy.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=ACCESSKEY&Signature=SIGNATURE&Expires=EXPIRATION"
```

I then deploy my application to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. All the same environment variables with AWS secrets are configured. But when I run the same request, I get a much longer URL that looks like this:

```
https://fiber-staging-pdfs.s3.amazonaws.com/pdf/liza/dummy.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=ACCESSKEY&Signature=SIGNATURE&x-amz-security-token=TOKEN&Expires=EXPIRATION
```

Somehow, the same code when run against this environment is adding a `x-amz-security-token` parameter? Why? And When I try to visit this generated URL, I get a 403 Forbidden error.

The Bucket Policy for this bucket is like:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "POLICYID",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "SID",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNTID:root"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKETNAME/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code on your EB instance uses [instance role](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=ec2+instance+role) to provide it with AWS credentials. When you do this, `x-amz-security-token` is used which is a regular part of AWS  [credentails](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_Credentials.html) when you use IAM roles.

In contrast, when you run it locally, you use IAM user for AWS credentials. In that case, token is not used.

Comment: I see, thanks. So does that mean I need to modify the Bucket policy principal to include an instance role?

Comment: @RommelTJ Yes, it should include ARN of the instance role. Alternatively, add S3 permissions to the instance role itself.